# Floating Action Button shows up in Arc style like Skype

Tags: java, android, android-studio, floating-action-button

I am customising a Floating Action button which expands to show a menu, I have achieved the FAB which expands a menu but I want add a background colour to it, and also the background colour for the menu that is expanded.

```
 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.notes_bottom_menu);  
    FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .setContentView(imageView)
            .build();

    ImageView iconName = new ImageView(this);
    iconName.setImageResource(R.drawable.create_note);
    ImageView iconDate = new ImageView(this);
    iconDate.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_coach);
    ImageView iconRating = new ImageView(this);
    iconRating.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
    SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);

    SubActionButton buttonName = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconName).build();
    SubActionButton buttonDate = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconDate).build();
    SubActionButton buttontRatings = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconRating).build();

    FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
            .addSubActionView(buttonName)
            .addSubActionView(buttonDate)
            .addSubActionView(buttonRatings)
            .attachTo(actionButton)
            .build();
```

This is an example picture of what I want to implement
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Hey dude if you have any idea regarding to your question pls let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this awesome library https://github.com/saurabharora90/MaterialArcMenu

Add a dependency to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.sa90.materialarcmenu:library:1.3'

}



<com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu
    android:id="@+id/arcMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:menu_scr="@drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
    app:menu_open="arc_left">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_map"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu>
```